# How do i approach these inheritance problem? (Pokemon Gen III)

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm currently making a Pokemon clone on Python just for the heck of it. After fiddling a bit with some GBA ROM editing tools, i've found out that on these games there are, among other things:

- Events placed on a map, each with a script that is run when you interact with it (Either by running into them or pressing the A button at them). 
  Examples of this are Signposts, hidden items, doors, and more importantly...
- NPCs, which, aside from having scripts (talking, triggering a pokemon battle, etc) can move and/or look around (at least some of them).
- The Player character, which can also move and look around, controlled by the human player or by some outside event that may be manipulating it. But the Player itself is not an event, as it has no associated event scripts on its own. It just triggers everyone else's.

So how should i go about recreating this with Python? By using multiple inheritance, i'd get something like this:

```
class Event(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y script):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.script = script

class Moving(object):
    ''' objects that can move '''
    def __init__(self, x, y, direction):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.direction = direction

    def move_one_space_to(self, direction):
        self.x += direction.x
        self.y += direction.y
        self.turn_to(direction)

    def turn_to(self, direction):
        self.direction = direction

class NPC(Event, Moving):
    def __init__(self, x, y, script, movetype):
        Event.__init__(self, x, y, script)
        Moving.__init__(self, x, y, DOWN)
        self.movetype = movetype

class Player(Moving):
    # many methods that an NPC shouldn't have go here
    pass
```

However, even though i may be sidestepping any problems that come with it, i'm still reluctant to use multiple inheritances. So...

Should i stick with this approach? 
And if not... why not? and can you post a better one?

Comment: "I'm currently a Pokemon clone"... I always wanted to become a Pokemon :( congrats on achieving what too many people dream of! ;)

Comment: Edited back to reality : (

Comment: I bet it was fun while it lasted :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a principle in software engineering called DRY which stands for [Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

You might notice that both `Event` and `Moving` have the properties `x` and `y`. This leads to a strange situation in your class `NPC`, which now has two pairs of coordinates, one inherited from `Event` and one inherited from `Moving`. You will have a hard time squishing all the bugs which result from these two getting out of sync.

When you observe duplication of properties, then you should consider to extract these into a common base class. In this case I would create a base-class like `GameObject` with the properties `x` and `y` and have anything inherit from it which has a location in the game world. `Moving` would then inherit from `GameObject` and add logic for changing the position (like finding and following paths from A to B).

Regarding your events: What you call `Event` isn't an event. It is an `EventTriggerArea` which causes an event to happen when the player steps into them. The event is the script attached to it (or rather the invocation thereof).

`NPC`s are also a source of events, but they are triggered completely differently (by pressing A while facing them, not by stepping into them). This is a case where two classes having the same property ("script") does not necessarily mean that they should have a common base-class, because the property *means* something differently for each.

A signpost is just an NPC with no movement behavior and a hidden item is just a signpost with no sprite. You said not all NPCs move around, which doesn't make them any different from signposts. So I would see how far I get with representing them with the NPC class. Or maybe you end up with an abstract base-class `NPC` with two inheriting classes `ImmobileNPC` (inheriting from `NPC` and `GameObject`) and `MobileNPC` (inheriting from `NPC` and `Moving`).

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is probably a bad idea, what will happen is you end up with all sorts of nonsensical unrelated things inheriting all sorts of related things.

This sort of class composition usually just creates problems and inflexible interfaces. If your NPC moves, give it a boolean. Since your NPC's movement is no doubt determined by its mind, or a path let it happen in the script during your game loop.
Additionally, your player while moving in reality is controlled. Completely different methods the only relation is in some real world concept of movement, not the code. Which is the inherent problem, it doesn't create any coherent relation to have them both subclass `Moving`.

Comment: This answer would be far more valuable when it would not just explain the drawbacks of the approach explained above but also provide some alternatives.